# It $f(x)=x+\sin x$, then can we find $f^{-1} (x)$?

Tags: functions, inverse

We have a bijective function $f(x)=x+\sin x$. So what is $f^{-1} (x)$?

Let $f^{-1}(x)$ be $g(x)$. Suppose we have to find $g\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ and $g'\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.

How to do it?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{1}{2}$ should look suspiciously like you could determine the value of $g$ by looking intensely. Then the value of $g'$ follows by the chain rule.

Comment: Well, looking at $y = f(x) = \dfrac{\pi} 6 + \dfrac 1 2$, can you think of *any* possibly $x$? Thinking of the well-known values of the sine function might help.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, that value appears at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, but is this procedure possible for any other value of $x$ in $g(x)$, say finding $g\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$?

Comment: @user157130 No, you cannot solve this equation analytically for arbitrary values. You could use numerical methods for finding approximate answers.

Comment: Not for $g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. But for $g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+1\right)$. The value $x$ was evidently hand-picked so that you can find $g(x)$.

Comment: Nope, there is no closed form for $f^{ −1} (y)$. You can find approximate inverses by using f(x)≈x+x(π−x) in range [0,+π] , then refining by Newton.

Comment: $f^{-1}(y)=y+u(y)$ where $u(y)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x+\sin x$ is strictly increasing, since its derivative, $1+\cos x$, is strictly positive, save on isolated points of the form $x=k\pi$, when $\cos x=-1$. So it follows that the function is bijective on **R**. So since $x=\dfrac\pi6$ is one obvious possible solution for $x+\sin x=\dfrac\pi6+\dfrac12$ , it follows that it is the *only* solution. Then, as far as the derivative of its inverse is concerned, we [know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) that $\bigg(f^{-1}\bigg)'(y)=$ $=\dfrac1{f'(x)}$ , where $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Yes..this can be easily seen if we sketch a figure..